# Azure AD B2C custom policies

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Is there any particular tutorial or guide to follow when creating customized policies in Azure AD B2C?

I have followed the tutorial in 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom 
so far.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That article which you've referenced is the official "Get Started" guide for Azure AD B2C custom policies:

https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom

The left menu contains more links for other custom policies scenarios such as:

- Configure OIDC providers - [Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-aad-custom)
- Configure SAML providers - [Salesforce SAML](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-setup-sf-app-custom)
- Integrate RESTful APIs - [Obtain additional claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-rest-api-step-custom)
- ...etc

**Important Note**: As per [StackOverflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), you should post specific questions adding as much information such as code, error messages, etc.